# Watchdog does not reboot the device when timeout expires

Tags: c++, watchdog, .net-micro-framework

When I deploy this to a single board computer, the light flashes continuously despite the [Watchdog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.watchdog%28v=vs.102%29.aspx). I expected a restart every ten seconds, because the [WatchdogBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.watchdogbehavior%28v=vs.102%29.aspx) is HardReboot and the [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.watchdog.timeout%28v=vs.102%29.aspx) is set. What am I missing?

```
namespace WatchdogTest
{
    using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

    public class Program
    {
        private static OutputPort led1 = 
            new OutputPort(GHI.Hardware.G120.Pin.P1_15, true);
        private static Timer timer;
        public static void Main()
        {
            Watchdog.Behavior = WatchdogBehavior.HardReboot;
            Watchdog.Enabled = true;
            Watchdog.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); // ten seconds

            timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, new object(), 0, 250);

            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(object stateInfo)
        {
            Flash();
        }

        private static void Flash()
        {
            bool isOn = led1.Read();
            led1.Write(!isOn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which board are you using?